# Unique Openers By Each Month

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a query which pulls information about unique openers in the last 30 days, but I would like to find this info for each month from the last 6 months.

Here's the query I wrote

```
Select o.subscriberkey from _open o
join _job j
on j.jobid = o.jobid
where o.eventdate > dateadd(d,-30,getdate())
and j.AccountID = ######
```

So I would like to get an output like this,

Jan 20 - XXX
Dec 19 - XXX
Nov 19 - XXX
Oct 19 - XXX
Sep 19 - XXX
Aug 19 - XXX

Can someone show me how to do this date filtering?

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: you want just the count, not the actual subscribers, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should give you what you need. Be careful though as depending on the volume of records in the Open DV, this can time out.

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(GetDate(), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy')

UNION

SELECT FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate()), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate()), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate()), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate()), 'yyyy')

UNION

SELECT FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-2,GetDate()), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-2,GetDate()), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-2,GetDate()), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-2,GetDate()), 'yyyy')

UNION

SELECT FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-3,GetDate()), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-3,GetDate()), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-3,GetDate()), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-3,GetDate()), 'yyyy')

UNION

SELECT FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-4,GetDate()), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-4,GetDate()), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-4,GetDate()), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-4,GetDate()), 'yyyy')

UNION

SELECT FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-5,GetDate()), 'MMMM') as Month,
FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-5,GetDate()), 'yyyy') as Year,
COUNT(SubscriberKey) as Count
FROM _open
WHERE FORMAT(eventdate, 'MMMM') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-5,GetDate()), 'MMMM')
AND FORMAT(eventdate, 'yyyy') = FORMAT(DateAdd(m,-5,GetDate()), 'yyyy')
```

Basically this iterates through the past 6 months (including current month) via each unioned select query and counts the opens inside of that month.

By utilizing DateAdd with GetDate, this will be future facing and will not need to be edited each time you need a new month.

Sample Output:

```
Month     |   Year   |  Count
January   |   2020   |  20192
December  |   2019   |  238923
November  |   2019   |  234233
October   |   2019   |  233423
September |   2019   |  343323
August    |   2019   |  543323
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
SELECT
x.SentMonth,
x.EmailName
FROM
(
SELECT
datename(month,s.EventDate) as SentMonth,
1 as Emails_Sent,
j.EmailName as EmailName
FROM
_Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON o.JobID = s.JobID AND o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID AND o.IsUnique = 1
INNER JOIN _Job j ON j.JobID = s.JobID
WHERE s.EventDate between '06/01/2019 00:00:00.000' and '01/31/2020 23:59:00.000'
) x
GROUP BY
x.SentMonth,
x.EmailName
```